# How to pass control from an event in a UIView to UIView Controller in Iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

**Scenario:**

I have a calendar control as a UIview and I want that when I click on date button of the view I want to navigate to some other UIview controller but when I use:

```
HomeView *scrhome=[[HomeView alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:scrhome animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It gives an error:
 HomeView is not in memory stack

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196871/memory-problems-when-pushing-many-view-controllers-on-uinavigationcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use observer Pattern

see you can create an observer using NSNotificationCenter:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notify) name:@"Event" object:nil];`      //1

put this in your view controller.

and a selector in view controller like:

```
-(void)notify 
{
    //2
    HomeView *scrhome=[[HomeView alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:scrhome animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and in your view write under a condition where you want to throw an event:
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Event" object:nil];` //3

and you are ready to go.

you may use object:yourobject in place of nil @ //1

and

```
id=sender;
```

if you want to get some attributes to work on.

it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

As schrome is UIView not a view controller,it can not be passed an argument as required type is uiviewcontroller. What you can do is use this uiview inside a controller and that viewcontroller's object can be passed as an argument.

Comment: HomeView is not a view its a view controller.

Answer (score -1):

**presentViewController:** expects to have view **controller** as a parameter, you are passing a view here. Have a controller for your view and pass it in **presentViewController: animated:**